# Cannot share directories between virtualbox and Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, files

I need to share the Desktop directory in order to copy some files I need from there. This is a Virtualbox and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.
But the "Desktopy" link is not showing up in the media directory.
How can I copy files from Windows to my VB?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use shared folders in VirtualBox, you will need to install the guest additions for VirtualBox. Once you install the guest additions you'll have the module that shared folders require. After that, you should be able to reboot into your VM and see your shared folder under `/media`.

You can also find a rather detailed thread about this on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm